# How can i add font for text in SVG? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I add text in svg image with font, but text font doesn't work. I download ttf of font, add in assets and pubspec. But after that it doesn't work either.

`<text fill="#e30a17" font-family="HelloShilla, Hello Shilla" font-size="36" transform="translate(557.26 282.1)">Hello</text>`

SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/myImage.svg")

Answer (score 0):

I replace file with font in SVG file and It helps me to solve It.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).